# How to get data from Stored Procedure in form of two tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have two tables 1. Staff 2. Clients

Each Staff has some Clients. I want to write an Stored Procedure that returns me staff name and its clients name and Clients address.
How can I achieve this?

I want to make a report from the returned result which will be like this:

[image]

This staff has three clients and their addresses are being shown respectively. This is just an example.

I can have more than one staff. This report is in simple HTML, I have to make it in SQL Server Reporting Services.

Comment: Can you add some more table details please? Are you familiar with JOINs?

Comment: Create a query that joins the Staff and Client tables together, and in SSRS, group by the staff name.  It's pretty simple to do.

Comment: yes I am familiar. By Tables I mean, as you can see in the example, it looks like two tables. One is returning staffs and the other one is returning its clients. That is what I mean.

Comment: @Brian Let me give it a try. Why this didn't come in my mind :@ :( Write it as answer here. I want to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a query that joins the Staff and Client tables together, and in SSRS, group by the staff name. It's pretty simple to do.